# SQL Server 2008 Results to File are incomplete, any ideas?

Tags: sql-server, function

I created a function that might result in a very large string. When I select the "Results to Grid" option and then I copy and paste the result to word or notepad the result is as I expected, but when I choose the "Results to file" option and I open the file I got the surprise that the result is not complete, its a truncated part of my complete string. The character count (with spaces) in word gives me 247 characters.

I think that it might be some configuration somewhere, but I cant find where....Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL Server Management Studio
. Tools
.. Options
... Query Results
.... SQL Server
..... Results to Text
...... Maximum number of characters displayed in each column (default is 256)
```

Comment: I already tried this, maximum number taht it allowed me was 8 thousand and something, but still the result was truncated at the same position